# Unable to see toast in cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, toast

I'm unable to see toast messages when testing with cypress.

I tried the test on browser and Command line, and also tried adding a wait.

```js
it('Login with invalid password', () => {
    login.enterEmail(testData.username)
    login.enterPassword(testData.invalidPassword)
    login.submit()
    cy.wait(2000)
    login.getToastError().contains(testData.invalidCredentialsError)
})
```

Any inputs regarding toast messages with cypress will be useful.

Comment: What does `login.getToastError()` this translates into ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you face is that the toast appears slowly (compared to test running speed).

**TLDR:**  Use `cy.contains('my-selector', 'my-text')`

---

Using `cy.get('my-selector').contains('my-text')` retries the text `my-text`, but not the existence of `my-selector`.

Using the format `cy.contains('my-selector', 'my-text')` will wait for the element to appear, then check it's text.

So, for a toast that has `id="toaster"`

```js
it('Login with invalid password', () => {
    login.enterEmail(testData.username)
    login.enterPassword(testData.invalidPassword)
    login.submit()
    cy.contains('#toaster', testData.invalidCredentialsError)  
})
```

Or pass the error text into `login.getToastError`

```js
it('Login with invalid password', () => {
    login.enterEmail(testData.username)
    login.enterPassword(testData.invalidPassword)
    login.submit()
    login.getToastError(testData.invalidCredentialsError)  
})
```

```js
// login - approximate revision

getToastError(errorMessage) {
  if (errorMessage) {
    cy.contains('#toaster', testData.invalidCredentialsError)
  } else {
    return cy.get('#toaster').invoke('text')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when I was needing to verify it was present and had the correct message. I probably didn't need the selector in the `.contains()` but it works.

```
cy.get('ion-toast').should('exist').shadow().contains('.toast-message','Invalid username or password.');
```

The `.shadow()` method was the magic to see the internals of the toast.

Comment: This is what I was looking for trying to test a toast in an Ionic app with Cypress. 

Makes sense since Ionic uses stencil, and stencil the web components, hence relies on shadow dom. 

The shadow() method was the magic for me too!

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for (also testing an Ionic app), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `login.getToastError()` translates into something like `cy.get('selector')` then you can do something like this:

For partial text match:

```js
it('Login with invalid password', () => {
  login.enterEmail(testData.username)
  login.enterPassword(testData.invalidPassword)
  login.submit()
  login
    .getToastError()
    .should('be.visible')
    .and('include.text', testData.invalidCredentialsError)
})
```

For exact text match:

```js
it('Login with invalid password', () => {
  login.enterEmail(testData.username)
  login.enterPassword(testData.invalidPassword)
  login.submit()
  login
    .getToastError()
    .should('be.visible')
    .and('have.text', testData.invalidCredentialsError)
})
```